# Apache SSL Request Certificate

Tags: django, apache, ssl, https

I installed a SSL certificate in my apache server and I am having a problem. It happens that when I open my site on my phone it opens lots of popups asking to setup a pin for credential storage. On Macs it also opens a popup asking to select a certificate. Does anyone have/had this problem? I am also using django on my server if I helps for the answer.

[image: what happens on android]

[image: what happends on Macs]

my ssl configuration is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin blahblah@blah.pt
        ServerName beta.site.pt
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vhost1-error.log

        WSGIDaemonProcess netpecasbeta user=${APACHE_RUN_USER} group=${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} threads=25 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup netpecasbeta
        WSGIScriptAlias / /.../wsgi.py
        <Location />
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
                RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName media.site.pt
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vhost1-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vhost1-access.log combined

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /.../netpecas.pt.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /.../netpecas.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /.../gd_bundle.crt
        SSLVerifyClient optional

        LimitRequestBody 0
        LimitRequestFieldSize 40940000
        LimitXMLRequestBody 0

        <Location />
                SSLRequireSSL On
                SSLVerifyClient optional
                SSLVerifyDepth 1
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin blabla@bla.pt
        ServerName beta.site.pt
        WSGIProcessGroup netpecasbeta
        WSGIScriptAlias / /partfy/woofparts/Partfy/wsgi.py

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vhost1-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vhost1-access.log combined

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /.../netpecas.pt.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /.../netpecas.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /.../gd_bundle.crt
        SSLVerifyClient optional

        LimitRequestBody 0
        LimitRequestFieldSize 40940000
        LimitXMLRequestBody 0
        <Location />
                SSLRequireSSL On
                SSLVerifyClient optional
                SSLVerifyDepth 1
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you post your Apache configuration, specifically the SSL section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change SSLVerifyClient from Optional to None, as specified here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient

Comment: it actually worked... whats the difference between optional and none in "being secure" things ?

Comment: `Optional` means the client can specify a _client_ certificate -- a means of identifying end-users, not websites -- if they want, but aren't required to. This setup is used by enterprise systems that distribute certificates to identify users. Setting it to `None` has no effect on the "HTTPS-ness" of your site, and indeed, my browser shows a nice green lock for http://beta.netpecas.pt with no annoying popups.